# MVC 3 Processing a table row depending on whether a check box is checked

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am very new to MVC and I am currently trying to implement a small human resources system using MVC 3 and Entity Framework 4.1. Right now I am stuck on what seems like a very trivial task of displaying a table which lists employees who have recently taken sick leave off from work and on each table row I have a checkbox which users will check if the the employee has provided a sick sheet. I also want to have a button/Link/etc on each row which when clicked would invoke a call to a controller method and somehow pass the checked value of the check box together with the id of the sick leave application. I tried using an actionlink but I'm kind of stumped at what I would enter in as the routevalue meant for the checked value of the checkbox. This same functionality would take me only minutes to do in web forms but like I said I'm new to MVC and since this seems like a pretty simple task there is probably a pretty simple solution somewhere out there but I just can't figure it out for the life of me. If anything I'm guessing this might need a bit of jquery (which btw still looks like a foreign language to me sometimes) and hidden fields? Arrgghhh I don't know. Could someone please help me?? Thanks in advance.

Here is my View:

```
    @model IEnumerable<LeaveSoft.Models.PendingSickLeave>

   <table>
    <tr>


     <th>
        Applicant's Name
    </th>

    <th>
        Leave Start
    </th>
    <th>
        Leave End
    </th>
    <th>
        Number Of Days
    </th>     

    <th>
        Reason
    </th>

    <th>
        Confirm
    </th>
    <th>

    </th>
</tr>

   @foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>


    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserFullName)
    </td>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NumOfDays)
    </td>


    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LeaveReason)
    </td>

    <td>
       @Html.CheckBox("chkConfirm")


            @Html.Label("", "Sick Sheet Provided")

    </td>

    <td>
       @Html.ActionLink("Process", "ProcessSickLeave", new { id = item.ApplicationID, sicksheet = "THIS IS THE PART I DON'T KNOW" }) 

    </td>    
</tr>
  }

</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a quick solution off the top of my head (table shortened due to my laziness):

**HTML/RAZOR**:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ApplicantName</th>
        <th>Confirm</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.PendingSickLeave) // this is a List<>
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@item.UserFullName</td>
        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => item.SickSheet, new { @id = "chk" + @item.ApplicationID })</td>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink("Process", "ProcessSickLeave", new { id = item.ApplicationID }, new { @class="submit", @data_val = item.ApplicationID })</td>    
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

**JQUERY SCRIPT**:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
            // captures click event. appends the sicksheet querystring on the url.
        $('a.submit').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).attr('data-val');
            var chk = $('#chk' + id);
            if ($(chk).is(':checked'))
                $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '?sicksheet=true');
            else
                $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '?sicksheet=false');
        });

    });
</script>
```

Basically, when you click on the Process actionlink, the jquery looks for a checkbox with matching ID, then if it's checked, it puts a `?sicksheet=true` at the end of the url before continuing.

edit:

**ROUTE**:

```
routes.MapRoute("ProcessSickLeave", "process/processsickleave/{applicationid}", 
                  new { controller = "Process", action = "ProcessSickLeave" });
```

**CONTROLLER**:

```
    public ActionResult ProcessSickLeave(ProcessViewModel m)
    {
        return Content("ID = " + m.ApplicationID + 
                  "<br/> Has Sick sheet: " + m.SickSheet.ToString(), "text/html");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the timely reply. I tried out your suggestion but I get the following error when I click on the process link: "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'SickSheet' of non-nullable type 'System.Boolean'...."